# Equation of equilibrium in a case where the partition allows particle exchange

Tags: statistical-mechanics, equilibrium

[image]

> ... two physical systems [seperated by wall], A1 and A2.  A1 has   $\Omega_{1}(N1,V1,E1)$ possible microstates, and the macrostate of A2  is $\Omega_{2}(N2,V2,E2)$

> ... at any time $t$, the subsystem $A_{1}$ is equally likely to be in any one of the $\Omega_{1}\left(E_{1}\right)$ microstates while the subsystem $A_{2}$ is equally likely to be in any one of the $\Omega_{2}\left(E_{2}\right)$ microstates; therefore, the composite system $A^{(0)}$ is equally likely to be in any one of the
> $$
> \Omega_{1}\left(E_{1}\right) \Omega_{2}\left(E_{2}\right)=\Omega_{1}\left(E_{1}\right) \Omega_{2}\left(E^{(0)}-E_{1}\right)=\Omega^{(0)}\left(E^{(0)}, E_{1}\right)
> $$

> ... if A1 and A2 came into contact through a wall that allowed an exchange of particles as well, the conditions for equilibrium would [include] the equality of the parameter $\zeta_{1}$ of subsystem $A_{1}$ and the parameter $\zeta_{2}$ of subsystem $A_{2}$ where, by definition,
> $$
> \zeta \equiv\left(\frac{\partial \ln \Omega(N, V, E)}{\partial N}\right)_{V, E, N=\bar{N}}
> $$

• So if we've a wall that allowed an exchange of particles we have from above equation:

$$
\left(\frac{\partial \ln \Omega_1(N_1, V_1, E_1)}{\partial N_1}\right)_{V_1, E_1, N=\bar{N}}
=\left(\frac{\partial \ln \Omega_2(N_2, V_2, E_2)}{\partial N_2}\right)_{V_2, E_2, N=\bar{N}}
$$

However having a wall that allows particles to be exchanged means no wall at all, then $V_1,V_2$ are not well defined, but the above equation uses them?

Answer (score 0):

We don't need a physical wall to define the volume of a portion of the larger box, but it makes it easier, imagine a volume with holes big enough for molecules to pass through.

For more fun drill holes of different size so small molecules can pass but larger cannot.